# How do I prevent a Github App API authentication from failing

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, github-api

I am building a simple process that requires access to Github App authentication to create and manage issues.
I am using this library: https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-GitHub

In the config, I opted to use the app connection method, so I created a new app in the organisation got the credentials and added them to the config array.

```php
...
'app' => [
   'method'       => 'application',
   'clientId'     => 'Iv1.5aa..............',
   'clientSecret' => 'ea6e9................'
   ...
]
```

(By the way, the main connection method works if I use a user token, but then all issues are created in my username which is not what I want.)

With every request, I am hit by a `Bad credentials in /Project/Path/vendor/knplabs/github-api/lib/Github/HttpClient/Plugin/GithubExceptionThrower.php on line 123` error.
Am I using the wrong credentials? Is there something I am missing?

Here is how I am implementing the Library in my Job class:

```php
class ProcessFeedback implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    public function handle(GitHubManager $github)
    {
         $issue = $github->issues()->show(
             config('services.github.owner', 'perfect-user'),
             config('services.github.repo', 'perfect-repo'),
             $number
         );
         
         dd($issue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks similar ~ https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-GitHub/issues/109